# SVG not correctly displayed inside IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I have various flags as svg-files. Inside Chrome or Firefox they are displayed correctly:

[image]

However when I go to the site with Internet Explorer 11 I only see this:

[image]

Funny thing is, when I select the flag in Developer-mode and set the width to 100% i get this:

[image]

So obviously IE seems to do some resizing with this, and I don't know why. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing a testcase. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: IE has some issues with SVG, did you specified the width/height? please see this for reference http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg